# How to calculate Height of any control which is loaded in DataTemplate?

Tags: height, uwp, datatemplate, uwp-xaml

I want to get the height of the control which is loaded in DataTemplate when the width is set to 100. I have used the below code, but always returns the size 0,20. Any suggestion on this?

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="dataTemplate">
  <Grid>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
   </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

var record = new UserInfo() { Name = "ASKL ALASO DKADOLD ADKIKAM AMDKI ADKAI AKDKI" };
var contentControl = new ContentControl();
contentControl.Measure(new Size());
contentControl.Content = record;
contentControl.ContentTemplate = App.Current.Resources["dataTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
contentControl.Measure(new Size(100, Double.PositiveInfinity));
var size = contentControl.DesiredSize;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have used the below code, but always returns the size 0,20. Any suggestion on this?

This is because you didn't render your `ContentControl` on the layout, you can render it for example like this:

```cs
var record = new UserInfo() { Name = "ASKL ALASO DKADOLD ADKIKAM AMDKI ADKAI AKDKI" };

var contentControl = new ContentControl();
stackPanel.Children.Add(contentControl);   //Add this ContentControl to the childeren collection of a StackPanel to show it
//contentControl.Measure(new Size());
contentControl.Content = record;
contentControl.ContentTemplate = App.Current.Resources["dataTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
contentControl.Measure(new Size(100, Double.PositiveInfinity));            
var size = contentControl.DesiredSize;
```

Then now, you can get the size of your `ContentControl`, by my side it is 94,100.

I'm not sure this size is the one you actually want, from your title, you want to  calculate Height of any control which is loaded in DataTemplate, but this size is the size of `ContentControl`, I think what you need is the height of the `Grid`, or `TextBlock` inside of this `ContentControl`. To get this two control, you can code like this after the `ContentControl` is fully rendered:

```cs
var grid = contentControl.ContentTemplateRoot as Grid;
var textblock = grid.Children.FirstOrDefault() as TextBlock;
```

And be aware that the `DesiredSize` is not the rendered size of the control, you can refer to the Remarks part of [UIElement.DesiredSize property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.desiredsize).